# How would i populate kubernetes with random environment variables?

Tags: kubernetes

I recently dived into containers and kubernetes

I am trying to set an environment variable so that it will randomly or selectively choose from a list of words...

so say I have 1 pod which returns "hello world"

If I set a custom variable as RETURN_THIS = ["world", "kubernetes", "universe"]

if i scale to 3, then the second pod will return "hello kubernetes" and the third will return "hello, universe"

if I add another.. it would return "hello world"

and so forth

Any ideas on how I might be able to do this?

Comment: If you dont need more meaningful names, hostname would come handy. This would be different inside each container. You can echo hostname. I dont think pod knows how many more instances exist and what is it's number out of total replicas.

Comment: @c0dec0de Thanks but I was looking for meaningful things.. for instance.. spreading out usage of id/passwords in different containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$RANDOM` bash function

```
size=${#RETURN_THIS[@]}
HELLO=RETURN_THIS$(( $RANDOM % $size ))
```